# random number with p(x)= x^(-a) distribution

Tags: matlab, random

How can I generate **integer** random number within [a,b] with below distribution in MATLAB:

> p(x)= x^(-a)
>   I want the distribution to be normalized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random values given a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827067/generate-random-values-given-a-pdf).
Only for `a = 2` will be `p` a density function.

Comment: No. It is not my question.

Comment: In that case, could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: In that case, probability is exponential. In my question it is power law.

Comment: The linked solution does not depend on the particular formulation/type of the probability density function.

Comment: But this code is not for integers. I need integer numbers

Comment: Excuse me, would you edit the code so that it works for p(x)=x^(-alpha) in interval[a,b]? I mean the parameter appears in the distribution function is not equal to parameter in the interval.

Comment: In your code, which parameter is random number with given distribution?

Comment: Mehrana, please stop changing the question and asking trivial things. Please take your time to understand basic Matlab syntax and the posted answer. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

For **continuous distributions**: [Generate random values given a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827067/generate-random-values-given-a-pdf)

For **discrete distributions**, as later it was specified in the OP:

The same rationale can be used as for continuous distributions: [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

So from mathematical point of view there is no difference, the Matlab implementation however is different. Here is a simple solution with your distribution function:

```
% for reproducibility
rng(333) 

% OPTIONS
% interval endpoints
a = 4;
b = 20;

% number of required random draws
n = 1e4;

% CALCULATION
x = a:b;
% normalization constant
nc = sum(x.^(-a));

% if a and b are finite it is more convinient to have the pdf and cdf as vectors
pmf = 1/nc*x.^(-a);

% create cdf
cdf         = cumsum(pmf);

% generate uniformly distributed random numbers from [0,1]
r = rand(n,1);

% use the cdf to get the x value to rs
R = nan(n,1);
for ii = 1:n
    rr = r(ii);
    if rr == 1
        R(ii) = b;
    else
        idx = sum(cdf < rr) + 1;
        R(ii) = x(idx);
    end
end

%PLOT
% verfication plot
f = hist(R,x);

bar(x,f/sum(f))
hold on
plot(x, pmf, 'xr', 'Linewidth', 1.2)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('Probability mass')

legend('histogram of random values', 'analytical pdf')
```

[image]

Notes:

- the code is general, just replace the pmf with your function;
- it is strange that the same parameter `a` appears in the distribution function and in the interval too.